# Animate two items moving away from each other until hitting container outline

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-animations

For an intro animation, I want to animate two elements away from each other based on the outer container width to make it work responsive. Absolute positioning didn't worked for me because initialy the two items has to touch each other or have a constant, fixed distance between them.

Here is a representation of the animation:

```css
body {
background: #707070;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
}

.animated .content {
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
  <h2>1. before animation</h2>
  <div class="content">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
    </svg>

    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="green" />
    </svg>
 </div>
</section>

<section class="intro animated">
    <h2>2. after animation</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <svg width="100" height="100">
        <rect width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
      </svg>

      <svg width="50" height="50">
        <rect width="50" height="50" fill="green" />
      </svg>
   </div>
</section>

<section class="intro animated">
    <h2>3. custom container size</h2>
  <div class="content" style="width: 80%;">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
    </svg>

    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="green" />
    </svg>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: "_I want to..._"[fill in the blank] is off topic here [with no effort from you to solve this.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9078341) - this is not the purpose of this site. We are happy to answer programming/debugging questions about code you have written. Give this a try, come back with some code that doesn't work and we'll help you out.

Comment: This documentation about [requestanAimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) and the examples there will get you rolling.

Comment: @RandyCasburn thank you for your constructive criticism, but my efforts in the community are beyond question. I have a question of logic here and I am limited in time. There is no lack of coding skills, so it makes no sense to present a non-working solution. But you have already helped me because your comment gave me an idea. I just animate the element with an condition until the left offset to its outer container reaches 0 and the right elements right offset. Thanks :)

Comment: fair enough - I wasn't questioning your "_efforts in the community_" - I was asking you for debugging details - I'll try to be clearer next time. Glad you're on your way. Best of luck an have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just added a div in the middle of SVGs, when you click on Container I will add animated class to the container. in CSS I will change dummy flex to auto

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click", function() {
  this.classList.add('animated');
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #707070;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid #f7f7f7;
}

.content.animated .dummy {
  flex: auto;
}

.dummy {
  flex: 0;
  transition: flex 1s;
}
```

```html
<section class="intro">
  <h2>Click on container</h2>
  <div id="container" class="content">
    <svg width="100" height="100">
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="blue" />
    </svg>

    <div class="dummy"></div>

    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="green" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</section>

</section>
```

Comment: Thank you that's a smart solution i was looking for! My approach was a little more complicated :)